# C++ char* as a class member

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I was wondering why below code works like this: I have `char*` member field in a class. When I create one object of this class and then create the second object, and then assign the second object to the first one, the change of `char*` class member in the first object should affect change in a second object. Why are the values different?

```
class A{
public:
    char* word;
    int* number;
    A(){
        word = new char[100];
        number = new int;
    }
};


int main()
{
    char* a = "lala";
    char* b = "baba";

    A a1;
    a1.word = a;
    *(a1.number) = 23;
    A a2;
    a2 = a1; //After that pointers should point to the same address, because a2.word = a1.word

    a2.word = b;
    *(a2.number) = 10;

    cout << a1.word << endl << a2.word << endl;
    cout << *(a1.number) << endl << *(a2.number) << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The theory of pointers suggests that the result should be:

```
Sample2
Sample2
10
10
```

But the result is:

```
Sample1
Sample2
10
10
```

For the `int*` as a class member the behavior is like the theory suggests.

Comment: You aren't using pointers for `a1` and `a2` - `a2 = a1;` creates a copy of `a1` and assigns it to `a2`, they don't refer to the same object

Comment: Any good reason for not using a string?

Comment: Also not a good idea to have member variables as public. Use getters and setters instead

Comment: @UnholySheep: nailed it. Better create an answer from it.

Comment: Also: *"For the `int*` as a class member the behavior is like the theory suggests."* - What does that mean? You have no `int*` in your example code, so you would have to add some code to explain what behavior you expected and observed

Comment: The values are different because after you assigned one to the other with `a2 = a1;`, you overwrote the value by doing `a2.word = sample2;`.

Comment: `*(a2.number) = 10;` and `a2.word = b;` do completely different things (As should be obvious by the differing syntax)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that right now :) Thanks for explanation.

Comment: _"I do not write any constructors."_ There is a constructor right there.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have added this constructor after editing question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you first assign `a2 = a1`, both pointers point to the same string (`sample1)`

But after you do `a2.word = sample2`, you're changing one of the pointers, but not changing the other pointer.

You would get the result you expected if you copied the string instead of assigning to the pointer:

```
std::strcpy(a2.word, sample2);
```

This would also change `sample1`, since that's where `a1.word` and `a2.word` point. So it's equivalent to

```
std::strcpy(sample1, sample2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not changing the pointed to value. You're changing the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your two instances `a1` and `a2` are not refered to by pointers.
So `a2 = a1;` creates a copy of `a1` and assigns that to `a2` -> They do not refer to the same object.

So when you do `a2.word = sample2;` you are *only* changing the pointer of `word` in the `a2` object, which as stated previously is different from the `a1` object

Answer (score 1):

Step by step:

```
A a1;
a1.word = sample1;
```

`a1.word` now points to `sample1`

```
A a2;
a2 = a1; //After that pointers should point to the same address, because a2.word = a1.word
```

Your comment is correct, `a2.word` now points to `sample1`

```
a2.word = sample2;
```

Now `a2.word` points to `sample2`. The assignment above does not copy `sample2` over `sample1`, it makes `a2.word` point to `sample2`.